# Matplotlib save file as JPEG encoder error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am trying to save a matplotlib figure as a JPEG file and am getting the following error. I'm not sure if it has to do with my install or with my code. therefore I have as well attached a sample program to perform that produces the error below. I have no issue with saving the figure as a .png or.pdf only an issue with .jpg

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simpleissue.py", line 36, in updateplot
    self.figure.savefig(savename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1814, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 172, in print_figure
    super(FigureCanvasQTAggBase, self).print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2259, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 584, in print_jpg
    return background.save(filename_or_obj, format='jpeg', **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1675, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 708, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0, 0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)], bufsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 480, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, e, a, im.encoderconfig)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 431, in _getencoder
    return encoder(mode, *args + extra)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Sample Code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class plot(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.Layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.xarray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        self.yarray = [6,7,5,4,2,1]

        update_btn = QPushButton("Save Plot", self)
        self.Layout.addWidget(update_btn, 1)
        update_btn.clicked.connect(self.saveplot)

        self.createplot()

        self.setLayout(self.Layout)

    def saveplot(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save Plot As", "plot.jpg", "*.jpg ;; *.png ;; *.pdf")
        savename = filename[0]
        if savename:
            self.figure.savefig(savename)

    def createplot(self):
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.ax.grid()
        self.plot = self.ax.plot(self.xarray, self.yarray,'o', marker = 'o', c= 'b')[0]

        self.Layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 2)
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appl = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = plot()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(appl.exec_())
```

Version Info:

Matplotlib 2.1.0

Pyqt5

Python 3.5

Pillow-3.1.2

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] of the issue, i.e. what is the minimal code that reproduces the issue? Is this dependent on using PyQt? If not, leave that out? Is is dependent on using custom file names, if not, hardcode it. Add all the versions of the respective libraries you are using and also add which system you are running this on. Did you try different backends? Include which backends fail.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have added additional Information about the system I am running this on. all of the features included in the example are necessary for the larger Application. I have only tested this on Ubuntu.

Comment: I think what @ImportanceOfBeingErnest means is that this example isn't *minimal* yet. There's a lot of stuff here that, while it may be necessary for your application, may *not* be necessary to reproduce the bug. Eliminating the excess will not only make it easier for us to figure out, but might lead to you finding the problem on your own.

Comment: This is not about what is necessary in the larger system, it is about solving the saving problem. Therefore create a [mcve] of the issue. This should be doable in 4 lines.

Comment: @AustinRussell. I tested on arch linux using matplotlib-2.1.0, python-3.6.2 and pillow-4.3.0, and it works fine for me. Do you have pillow installed, or are you using PIL - and which version?

Comment: I understand, Give me a moment and I will produce a better example. I am using Pillow-3.1.2. That may the issue as well, I will try updating

Comment: Updating Pillow has fixed my issue. thank you all for your help. For the record I ran the command `sudo pip3 pillow --upgrade` if anyone else encounters this issue

Comment: Would you like to add your previous version of Pillow to the question and then provide an answer to your question? You can then accept your own answer in 2 days time such that this question is marked as answered and will not stay unsolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was corrected by updating Pillow. The following command was run: `sudo pip3 pillow --upgrade`